# ios (xcode 11): linking with a moron-vended static library with device slice only

Tags: ios, xcode

Suppose I have received a static library with arm64 slice only.
Is there a straightforward way to exclude that from simulator builds?
Thanks.

Comment: I would create a new target by duplicating the existing one, remove the static lib, and use this target only for simulator builds. however, this is maybe not so convenient.

Comment: yes, that's an obvious but not an acceptable way out